# angular grid layout explanation

Tags: angular, grid

I understand the basic angular grid layout in that it is 12-column system in any given row. But it can get pretty confusing sometimes. I am not sure how to interpret the following grid layout:

```
<div class="container widgets">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 widget-cont">
      <div class="widget">
          1.<app-blank></app-blank>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12 widget-cont">
      <div class="widget">
        2.<app-blank></app-blank>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-6 col-md-12 widget-cont">
      <div class="widget">
        3.<app-blank></app-blank>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-12 widget-cont">
      <div class="widget" id="graph-single-reach">
        4.<app-blank></app-blank>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

when displayed in the web page, it looks like below:

[image]

I can see 1 and 2 add up to 12 columns, so did 3 and 4, but how do those `col-lg-12`, `col-lg-6`, `col-md-12` etc work into this layout???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of class setting is for defining position of component when browser is resized.

The first setting in the class list of each `widget-cont` `div` is for default layout when horizontal space is unlimited. The second setting in the list is when the browser is resized to be smaller, in that case, component-2 can't stay in the same row as component-1 anymore, hence it re-arranges to be on the same row as component-3, each takes up half the space (i.e. `col-lg-6`) as shown below:

[image]

When the browser is narrowed down even more, then the last setting in the class list takes effect, hence, both component-2 and component-3 become `col-md-12`, while component-1 and component-4 both already become `col-lg-12`, i.e. every blank-component occupies entire row by itself, hence the whole layout turns into single column as below:

[image]